# AngularJS - Custom ExceptionHander not always working

Tags: angularjs, exception

I've been trying to figure out how to send Client Side Exceptions to a Server for logging in an AngularJS application.

I've followed the following steps posted here:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-Logging-Client-Side-Errors-With-AngularJS-And-Stacktrace-js.htm

This is working fine for some errors but does not seem to catch exceptions thrown in my directives.

E.g. my overriding of the exception handler:

```
app.provider("$exceptionHandler", {
    $get: function( errorLogService ) {
        return( errorLogService );
    }
});
```

This works fine for exceptions from controllers but my directive just doesn't seem to go through my custom exception handler - it just logs directly to the console e.g.

```
app.directive('saveAndShowDialog', function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.on('click', function(e) {

            var x = y; // forces exception
            scope.save();       

        });
    }
    return { restrict: 'A', link: link };
})
```

;

Can anyone give any direction as I've spent days on this and can't seem to get anywhere?

Thanks,
Kevin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try surrounding your event callback code with a $timeout. I suspect your code is running outside of Angular-land so wrapping in a $timeout will have your code block execute in the next Angular digest loop and have it handled properly by Angular's `$exceptionHandler`.

```
app.directive('saveAndShowDialog', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.on('click', function(e) {
            $timeout(function(){
                var x = y; // forces exception
                scope.save();       
            });
        });
    }
    return { restrict: 'A', link: link };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I made my google analytics exception logging:

```
module.config(function ($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {

    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', '$delegate', function ($injector, $delegate) {
      var Analytics, $location;
      return function exceptionSiren (exception, cause) {
        $delegate(exception, cause);

        var Analytics = Analytics || $injector.get('Analytics');
        var $location = $location || $injector.get('$location');
        Analytics.send('event', {
          eventCategory: 'exception',
          eventAction: exception.message,
          eventLabel: exception.stack.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"\n ○ "),
          page: $location.url(),
          nonInteraction: true
        });
        Analytics.sendException(exception.message, 
          exception.stack.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"\n ○ "));
      }
    }]);
});
```